# Can I add a custom paragraph delimiter?

Tags: cursor-motions

Paragraphs are delimited by empty lines, both in vim and tex, but sometimes I wish vim to treat an entity as a paragraph and not tex. Can I, e.g., make vim treat lines containing only a "%" as a paragraph delimiter?

Comment: See my answer to a similar question here: http://vi.stackexchange.com/a/6043/4932  also check out this plugin: https://github.com/vim-scripts/Improved-paragraph-motion

Comment: @Lawrence DOS line endings? Are you on Linux using a Windows file?

Comment: Plugin looks very interesting, but I got an error loading it: `Error detected while processing /Users/lawrence/.vim/plugged/Improved-paragraph-motion/plugin/ipmotion.vim:
line   50:
E492: Not an editor command: ^M
line   51:
E15: Invalid expression: exists('g:loaded_ipmotion')^M
line  145:
E171: Missing :endif`

Comment: @fruglemonkey, no, I'm using a Mac ...

Comment: @fruglemonkey, as far as I can understand the error was in the plugin. error messages went away after `:set ff=unix`.

Comment: The plugin affects only } and { motions, not text-objects.

Comment: Yeah, but you can otherwise create mappings that will let it behave 'like' a text object. Why do you want a custom paragraph delimiter? What action do you want to perform that would require one?

Comment: @fruglemonkey, did it and it seems to work fine. sometimes I want to keep equations in the same paragraph as the surrounding text, but not format the source of the equation.

Comment: @Lawrence: According to your last comment it seems that you found a solution. For my curiosity and for the other users who might be looking up your question it would be nice if you made an answer with your solution :-)

Comment: @statox, I did something that I don't quite understand and probably isn't a very good solution, so I won't post it as an answer, but: `vnoremap it <esc>:set nohls<cr>"q?^$\\|%<cr>jV"q/^$\\|%<cr>k
omap it <c-u><c-v>:normal! Vit<cr>`

Comment: @statox, one problem is that this contaminates the search register.

Comment: @Lawrence indeed that seems to be a pretty messy solution you were right not to post it as an answer :-)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot natively make `%` a pagraph delimiter, as paragraph macros are nroff macros (a dot, two characters: `.xx`)

However, you can add `.%%` (or any other combination you want) as a paragraph delimiter by adding it do the `paragraphs` option:

```
:set paragraphs=IPLPPPQPP\ TPHPLIPpLpItpplpipbp%%
```

See: `:help paragraph`:

```
A paragraph begins after each empty line, and also at each of a set of
paragraph macros, specified by the pairs of characters in the 'paragraphs'
option.  The default is "IPLPPPQPP TPHPLIPpLpItpplpipbp", which corresponds to
the macros ".IP", ".LP", etc.  (These are nroff macros, so the dot must be in
the first column).  A section boundary is also a paragraph boundary.
Note that a blank line (only containing white space) is NOT a paragraph
boundary.
Also note that this does not include a '{' or '}' in the first column.  When
the '{' flag is in 'cpoptions' then '{' in the first column is used as a
paragraph boundary posix.
```